# How to create/compile an exe which contains two other files?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio

I have two files, both of them are exe. One for 32bit, and one for 64bit. I'd like to create a small program(a third exe) in C, which contains these two files. When i start my third exe, it should do some work, and execute one of them. Is this somehow possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is called [Fat binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_binary) and AFAIK Windows don't support them. You could play dirty tricks. Why not install both binaries + your launcher and choose (at runtime) which you would run.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Windows doesn't support it? I seen such things on Windows. For example ProcessExlorer from Sysinternals works on the same way. Or i misunderstood something?

Comment: @kampi - what he means is Windows doesn't support this feature at the OS level, unlike Mac OS X for example. But you can make your own executable packer/unpacker to do this. I asked a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170643/any-tools-available-for-packing-32bit-64bit-executables-together) and there are some useful responses.

Answer (score 1):

### Doing it yourself in C

There are ways to implement this kind of thing in C/C++ described [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2005/09/19/multi-platform-images.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4221/Adding-and-extracting-binary-resources). Basically you do the following:

1. Add your 32-bit and 64-bit executables as binary PE resources to a 32-bit bootstrapper executable. You can do this using any PE resource editor including Visual Studio if that's what you're using.
2. The bootstrapper uses the `IsWow64Process` [API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms684139(v=vs.85).aspx) to decide whether it is running on a 64bit system or not.
3. The bootstrapper extracts the correct executable file from its resources using the [resource APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468902(v=vs.85).aspx)
4. The bootstrapper writes the executable file to a temporary file and executes it.

This is pretty much what I had to do for an old project, and offers you the most control and flexibility. But if you just want quick and dirty...

### Making AutoIT do it for you!

I also found [this guide](http://chentiangemalc.wordpress.com/2011/02/06/creating-a-single-exe-when-you-need-a-separate-exe-to-run-on-x86-and-x64-platforms/) to compiling an [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) script which basically does all of the above for you! Neat, eh?

I will reproduce the AutoIT script here in case the link disappears:

```
; Check if we’re on 64-bit OS…
If EnvGet(“PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432″)=”” Then
    ; No we’re not – run x86 version…
    FileInstall(“D:\Support\ETrustCheck_x86.exe”,@TempDir & “\ETrustCheck_x86.exe”)
    RunWait(“D:\Support\ETrustCheck_x86.exe”,@TempDir & “\ETrustCheck_x86.exe”)
    FileDelete(@TempDir & “\ETrustCheck_x86.exe”)
Else
    ; Yes we are – run x64 version..
    FileInstall(“D:\Support\ETrustCheck_x64.exe”,@TempDir & “\ETrustCheck_x64.exe”)
    RunWait(“D:\Support\ETrustCheck_x86.exe”,@TempDir & “\ETrustCheck_x64.exe”)
    FileDelete(@TempDir & “\ETrustCheck_x64.exe”)
EndIf

; The END
```

This script can be wrapped by the AutoIT script editor into 32bit launcher with your two executables packed into it.